# Calculate approximate cost of service based on companies' revenue

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

We create bespoke web designs and we always get asked how much the designs will cost without even knowing the job. Some people don't like to be asked for their budget, some can't understand how hourly rate works either, so, to simplify things we came up with some sort of formula.

**The idea is this - calculate an approximate price of the design based on their companies revenue. Their revenues are public on Latvian companies' register.**

So, if the companies' revenue is 100,000 USD per year, we would say the starting price is 1,750 USD (that is 0.0175 of their revenue).
If the revenue is 300,000 USD the price would be 1,950 USD (0.0065 of the revenue). Design for a company which has a revenue of 10,000,000 would cost ~8,500.

P.S. the minimum price would be, let's say - 1,600 (or something similar).

**More examples:**
-  100,000 USD revenue - 0.0175 ratio = 1,750 USD
-  300,000 USD revenue - 0.0065 ratio  = 1,950 USD
-  500,000 USD revenue - 0.0045 ratio  = 2,250 USD
-  1,000,000 USD revenue - 0.0035 ratio  = 3 500 USD
-  2,000,000 USD revenue - 0.0025 ratio  = 5,000 USD
-  10,000,000 USD revenue - 0.0085 ratio  = 8,500 USD
... etc ...

So, for example, if our X is 100000 and we would put it in to our formula we would get an output of 1750.

Note: these are just examples, **we don't need to get those exact numbers - what we want is just some sort of approximation for a quote.**

The function does not need to be a one line function, we could make a program out of it for the "ifs".

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You already have a table ($X$ revenue maps to $Y$ ratio), and you don't need a nice "one line function". What it is the real question? Do you want a curve fitting these given points to provide the mapping for intermediate values?

Comment: Well, those Y (ratio) values are "static" in this example. I though (and asked) if maybe, we could use some combination of lon/lg/cos/root/% on the X (revenue) to create a "dynamic" ratio value. I did try to use a formula generation tool which, as you suggested, maps values to ratios... but those ratios have to be entered statically. So, if, for example, we would want to get a quote for a revenue of 33kk - we would need to enter a new ratio in to the table.